# Performing function in new column based on condition in other column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Here I am attempting to query a column in dataframe df, which has boolean values 'Yes' or 'No', in order to perform some function of random letter assignment according to a probability distribution in rows where the condition is met.

```
if (df['some_bool'] == 'Yes'):
    df['score'] = np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], len(df), p=[0.3, 0.2, 0.5])
```

What is a correct way of writing this as I receive the following error for the above:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
df['score'] = np.where(df['some_bool'] == 'Yes', 
                       np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], len(df), p=[0.3, 0.2, 0.5]), '')
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! How would you write this to also handle the df['some_bool'] == 'No' condition?

Comment: It's easy...assuming that df['some_bool'] only has 'Yes' and 'No' values, simply replace the `''` with your intended value.  For example: `df['score'] = np.where(df['some_bool'] == 'Yes', np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], len(df), p=[0.3, 0.2, 0.5]), 'VALUE_IF_NO')`

Comment: Amazing. And can np.where handle non-binary conditions, where there may be 3 or more conditions?

Comment: If you have a small amount of conditions (3), you could nest another `np.where` function where the `VALUE_IF_NO` value currently resides.  However, I suggest changing the code to use `np.select` for multiple conditions.